# Nginx running on Debian lenny, how to add SSL?

Tags: debian, nginx, ssl, debian-lenny

Some time ago I installed Nginx and Passenger on Debian lenny with...

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo gem install passenger
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

This is what I get when I do `nginx -V`

```
nginx version: nginx/0.7.61
built by gcc 4.3.2 (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 
configure arguments: --prefix=/opt/nginx --with-pcre=/tmp/pcre-7.8 --add-module=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.5/ext/nginx
```

Now I want to add SSL support to Nginx, what's the best, simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HttpSSLModule for nginx? Should be build into the nginx package and you can setup using the config here http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule

```
  listen 443 default_server ssl;
  ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;
```

inside your `server{}` config block.

EDIT:

Using `passenger-install-nginx-module` will by default install nginx from source. To install the SSL module, you will need to download the source yourself. You can download the source yourself using `wget -O - http://nginx.org/download/nginx-0.7.69.tar.gz | tar -zx -C /tmp/` to extract the source to `/tmp/nginx-0.7.69`. Then rerun `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module`. Select option 2 (advanced) to pass extra arguments to the configure script. When prompted, enter `/tmp/nginx-0.7.69` as your source directory. You can keep `/opt/nginx` as the install directory. When prompted for extra arguments, enter `--with-http_ssl_module`. Confirm the configure line, then let it build and install.

Comment: No, the SSL module is not there. Trying to use the ssl directive results in unknown directive. Using nginx -V doesn't show the SSL module.

Comment: Odd, just looked up the package at http://packages.debian.org/lenny/nginx and it depends on libssl, so the SSL module should be there, can you post the results of your nginx -V? Also, since lenny is on 0.6.32 of nginx, you would have to remove the `default_server ssl` directive as that is just for >=0.7.14. Instead, set `ssl on;` in your `server {}` block.

Comment: Please, see the results of nginx -V in the (edited) original question. Actually Nginx is 0.7.61 . Maybe I updated Nginx, but I really don't remember. Anyway, the problem remains, SSL module is not installed.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my notes about how I installed Nginx in this server are wrong, as `dpkg -l '*' | grep nginx` doesn't show anything, and I guess that means that I didn't install the package, but I installed it from source.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention. When you did `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module`, by default it will download a source version of nginx and compile it. You will need to redo this, but select option 2 (the advanced option) to pass the `--with-http_ssl_module` directive to nginx's configure script. For this you will need to download the source for nginx yourself from http://nginx.org/en/download.html.